# Android use WCF(webservice)

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services, wcf

I am a freshman in android development. Today I use KSOAP2 to use WCF which I have finished on the server. Firstly, I try to use the WCF in windows form. It runs OK and the data have been upload. Then I use WCF with KSOAP2. The string cannot send well and the error is :
Method threw 'org.ksoap2.SoapFault' exception.
The detial of the error is:
a:InternalServiceFault
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s

I do not have the parameter named 's' in server program and android program. The vision of .NET is framework 4.0.
If I use .NET framework 4.5, The android can use it with KSOAP2.
However, I must use 4.0
How can I solve this problems?
Cheers.

The code in android is shown below:

```
 transferthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true)
                {

                        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
                        int a = 1;
                        request.addProperty("userid",a);
                        request.addProperty("healthData",info);
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.bodyOut = request;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                        try {
                            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                           // final SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                            envelope.getResponse();
                            Log.e("str",envelope.getResponse().toString());
                            a=1;
                            //Log.e("aaa",envelope.getResponse().toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            }
        });
        transferthread.start();
```

I think is the ksoap2 problem.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is another alternative solution for your question about how to implement Android use WCF. I used to give a try on KSOAP2. For some reason (I forgot) I give up using it.

This is what I am doing to do the same thing.

You can install Wizdler(Chrome-extension) to generate your envelope. and copy paste to envelope code.

Call getYourData in your asynctask.

```
public ArrayList<YourData> getYourData(String username, String password) {
ArrayList<YourData> resultList;
String resultData;
try {
    //Put your envelope here.
    final String envelope = "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n" +
            "    <Body>\n" +
            "        <Something xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/RemoteServices/url/\">\n" +
            "            <!-- Optional -->\n" +
            "            <request>\n" +
            "                <Authentication xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/RemoteServicesv2.Core\">\n" +
            "                    <Password>" +
            password +
            "</Password>\n" +
            "                    <Username>" +
            username +
            "</Username>\n"
            "        </Something>\n" +
            "    </Body>\n" +
            "</Envelope>";

    resultData = CallWebService(URL, "http://www.example.com/webserviceURL", envelope);
    Log.e("resultData for Something", ""+resultData);
    resultList = parseFunction(resultData);
} catch (Exception e) {
    resultList = null;
}
return resultList;
```

}

```
// How to send SOAP envelope to web service
private String CallWebService(String url,
                              String soapAction,
                              String envelope) {
    final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // request parameters

    HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 20000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 25000);
    // set parameter
    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpClient.getParams(), true);

    // POST the envelope
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    // add headers
    httppost.setHeader("soapaction", soapAction);
    httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

    String responseString = "";
    try {

        // the entity holds the request
        HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(envelope);
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Response handler

        ResponseHandler<String> rh = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
            // invoked when client receives response

            public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                    throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

                // get response entity
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                // read the response as byte array
                StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
                byte[] b = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);

                // write the response byte array to a string buffer
                out.append(new String(b, 0, b.length));

                return out.toString();
            }
        };

        responseString = httpClient.execute(httppost, rh);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("exception", e.toString());
    }

    String xml = responseString.toString();
    // close the connection
    System.out.println("xml file ------" + xml);
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    return responseString;
}
```